# Website performance slow for few users & very fast for others

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, iis, windows-server

I am facing a performance issue with one of our website build based of angularJS & .net, which is internal use only website of my company. It's brand new website, so not more than couple people using it. it is hosted on IIS/widows server 2016. For few the website comes right away including me in seconds. but for some users its loading up to 30 seconds even if we refresh multiple times the performance is same. its not browser cache issue because i tried clearing cache on my machine  or tried incognito mode too still my speed is less than two seconds. it's not internet speed to because for them i tried to load on company's network which is same for everyone..please let me know if anything i am missing or what needs to checking....

Comment: Please enable failed request tracing, you will see which process take the longest time.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis. If the low performance is caused by asp.net pipeline, then you need to capture dump snapshot and montior the stack trace. So that you will find the root cause.

Comment: I have identified the issue. Problem is with Authentication in IIS. Currently, It's enabled with ASP.NET Impersonate & windows authentication, I guess for some of the windows users it is identifying windows user name slowly that's why it's delayed. but, to check if I change to anonymous authentication it is fetching quickly with in couple seconds..but the problem is we are using windows username as person who creates requests in our page, so now without windows auth , I am not getting created by..please suggest if there is any other of doing this..

Comment: Emmm..What provider are you using? NTLM or kerberos? I mean you are trying to access the website via domain or IP? Have you tried to add the website to trusted website or local intranet?  If you are using kerberos ticket, then network monitor can be used to troubleshooting the process. It sounds like an AD network issue more than IIS issue.

Comment: I narrowed down to see what is the difference, the difference is I have administrator rights on hosted server also people who are getting faster response have admin access on the server. I also, tried to add a regular windows user to hosted server as admin, they also get the faster response. and provider setting in IIS are negotiate, NTLM. we are accessing site with domain

Answer (score 0):

Check two more things:

1. IIS Worker Processes
2. SQL `sysprocesses`

Open *IIS*, choose web server on the left side panel and open ***Worker Processes***.

[image]

Open *SQL Server Management Studio* and type query

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE
    blocked != 0
```

Login to your application using user's username and password that reported the issue. Login from another machine that is working properly and execute those *slow* actions.

Refresh continuously both *IIS* and *SSMS* and see if you can catch a problem, what is slowing down the application.

Do the same experiment on the machine where issue happened, but using user's credentials who didn't report the problem.

This way you will know if problem stems from user, or from the machine and if it happens on the web server, database server, or on the machine.

Finally, it is possible the problem is to much JavaScript generated by the frontend. This could be if *IIS* and *SSMS* don't show any sign of slowdown and if problem persists on the same machine, despite the different user login.

Comment: Hi Marko, We don't need to login to use this website, but i am suspecting the same as user issue. I realized all users who is getting faster response have access to the windows server that this website is deployed, people who don't have access to hosted server usually experiencing this problem. does it makes any difference? is there any setting on IIS that is restricting that way?

Comment: Hi Ravi, I think IIS is not handling it, not that I know. Client doesn't need to have access to web server, IIS generates the web page and sends it to client, therefore access to the server should not be the reason. But it cannot be a coincidence. Although I think IIS is not responsible for the issue, it sounds like you could get some answers trying the first approach, with Worker processes. I suppose when you say user, you mean user accounts?

Comment: I have identified the issue. Problem is with Authentication in IIS. Currently, It's enabled with ASP.NET Impersonate & windows authentication, I guess for some of the windows users it is identifying windows user name slowly that's why it's delayed. but, to check if I change to anonymous authentication it is fetching quickly with in couple seconds..but the problem is we are using windows username as person who creates requests in our page, so now without windows auth , I am not getting created by..please suggest if there is any other of doing this..